# How to show User List in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

My Home Controller of User List Method and How to call _Layout.chtml in @Html.Partial("_UserList"); not calling and please help me Sir.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult UserList()
    {
        var applicationDbContext = _context.Users.Include(a => a.Departments).Include(a => a.Positions); 
        return PartialView("_UserList", applicationDbContext);
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear! Are you trying to insert `@Html.Partial("_UserList")` in your layout page, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, but my best reasoning is that you're getting just a partial document rendered in the browser, without any layout, and you want the layout.

The reason for that is simply that you're return `PartialView`, which explicitly excludes layout. Instead, you need to return `View` like your actions are doing. Then, you should be using an actual view rather than your `_UserList` partial. In that view, you can call your partial:

```
@model List<ApplicationUser>

<partial name="_UserList" />
```

However, if I had to guess even further, I'd say that your ultimate goal is to have this user list rendered as part of your layout, while still being able to utilize other models/views. For that you should utilize a view component:

```
public class UserListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UserListViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var userList = await _context.Users.Include(a => a.Departments).Include(a => a.Positions).ToListAsync();
        return View(userList);
    }
}
```

Then, create the view `Views\Shared\Components\UserList\Default.cshtml`, and add your HTML for rendering the list of users there (what is likely the content of `_UserList.cshtml` currently). Finally, add the following line where you want the list of users to appear:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("UserList")
```